# Why does the word "vite" stay the same in adjective AND adverb form?

Tags: adverbes

Shouldn't it become "vitement" in adverb form?

Are there any other words that remain in the same form as adjectives and adverbs?

Comment: Why should there be a reason ?

Comment: How is it with "fast" ?

Comment: vite n'est plus utilisé comme adjectif, mais seulement comme adverbe.

Comment: @guillaume : sauf par les commentateurs sportifs :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Vite* est essentiellement utilisé comme adverbe mais on le rencontre exceptionnellement comme adjectif, souvent par des commentateurs sportifs:

> Il est vite ! = il est rapide !

Contrairement à une idée courante, il ne s'agit pas techniquement d'une faute de français ou d'un anglicisme car *[vite](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vite)* est un adjectif attesté depuis le moyen-âge et il est toujours considéré comme tel aujourd'hui.

Voir les articles de l'[oqlf](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2895), du [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/vite/82250), cette [page](http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/vite-a11752266), des exemples d'utilisation dans ce [titre récent](http://www.autonewsinfo.com/2016/11/11/hamilton-le-plus-vite-de-la-1ere-session-des-essais-libres-a-sao-paulo-devant-max-verstappen-et-nico-rosberg-210750.html) :

> HAMILTON **LE PLUS VITE** DE LA 1ère SESSION DES ESSAIS LIBRES A SAO PAULO DEVANT MAX VERSTAPPEN ET NICO ROSBERG.

et cette [page](http://www.trimes.org/2016/10/jean-paul-ballard-de-swiss-side-nous-presente-le-cube-c68-le-velo-probablement-le-plus-vite-du-monde/) :

> Jean-Paul Ballard de Swiss side nous présente le Cube C:68. Le vélo « probablement » **le plus vite du monde**.

Il existe d'autres mots employés à la fois comme adjectifs et adverbes, par exemple *cher* et *bon*:

> Ils sont chers (adj.)
>
> Ça coûte cher (adv.)
>
> Les fraises sont bonnes (adj.)
>
> Elles sentent bon (adv.)

Il y a aussi *mal* mais qui a la particularité de ne pas s'accorder:

> On est mal (= adj.)
>
> Ils sont mal (= adj. invariable) -> <s>Ils sont mals</s>.
>
> Elle est mal  (= adj. invariable) -> <s>Elle est male</s>.
>
> Bon gré, mal gré ( ~= de bon gré, de mauvais gré)

Comment: Hmm… il évite ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Oui, il est très vite ! ;)

Comment: J'ai pensé que la forme propre est "Ils sont mauvais." Pas "Ils sont mal." Parce que "mauvais" est utilisé comme un adjectif et "mal" est un adverbe. N'est-ce pas?

Comment: Oui, mal est un adverbe utilisé ici comme un adjectif. Attention, les sens de « ils sont mauvais » et « ils sont mal » sont différents (*They are nasty* vs *They are in trouble*.)

Comment: *Vite* n'est **jamais** utilisé comme un adjectif dans le français d'aujourd'hui.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez S'il n'était **jamais** utilisé comme adjectif, comment expliquer le contenu de [cette page](http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/vite-a11752266) ?

Comment: @jlliagre - je partage un peu la réaction de Stéphane. Quand je vois: _HAMILTON LE PLUS VITE_, je pense automatiquement que c'est une erreur, ou mauvais. Bien sûr, les dictionnaires signalent que _vite_ est un adjectif, et qu'on peut l'utiliser comme adjectif, mais je crois que l'on peut aussi affirmer que cet usage est très déclinant, et que nous sommes de plus en plus étonnés quand nous entendons _vite_ utilisé en tant qu'adjectif.

Comment: @Frank C'est au contraire un usage récent et qui croît, spécialement dans la bouche des commentateurs sportifs.

Comment: @Frank Oui, j'ai très rarement vu *vite* utilisé comme un adjectif dans la presse écrite. C'est essentiellement à la télévision ou la radio qu'on peut l'entendre.

Comment: Ah oui, vous avez raison: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vite_ADJ&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvite_ADJ%3B%2Cc0. Mais si l'on ajoute _rapide_ADJ_, ce dernier éclipse complètement _vite_. Evidemment, ngrams ne regarde que l'écrit.

Comment: Je suis heureux d'apprendre que les commentateurs sportifs sont très versés dans les nuances de la langue française depuis le moyen-âge ;-) Sans nul doute l'heureuse _coïncidence_ à laquelle vous faisiez allusion.

Comment: @Frank C'est bien pour ça que j'ai écrit ailleurs: *reviving by **coincidence***. C'est un usage erroné qui se trouve ne pas l'être par hasard.

Answer (score 7):

*Vitement* exists, as a matter of fact. It is an old word that never really came into wide use. It practically disappeared at the end of the 19th century.

*Vite* just slipped from an adjective to an adverb. It probably just passed unnoticed through the 16th century standardization of the French language.

One good source is the TLFI[1](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vite).

Answer (score 0):

En complément sur l'emploi adjectival uniquement. Tel qu'on l'avait déniché dans une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/23082/26366) :

> L’emploi de *vite* comme adjectif fut courant jusqu’au XVIIIe siècle;
> *vite* se disait alors autant pour une rapidité psychologique que physique; il a par la suite été concurrencé puis presque éclipsé, dans
> la langue générale, par l’adjectif *rapide*. En fait, *vite* ne
> s’emploie à peu près plus que dans le vocabulaire sportif, en parlant
> d’un athlète.
>
> Au Québec toutefois, l’emploi adjectival est encore courant, surtout
> dans la langue familière; que l’on pense, par exemple, aux expressions
> *être vite en affaires* ou *vite sur ses patins*, ou encore lorsqu’on dit de quelqu’un qu’*il n’est pas vite*, pour signifier qu’il est lent
> à faire ou à comprendre des choses.
>
> Dans la langue plus soutenue, il semble que, comme ailleurs dans la
> francophonie, l’adjectif *vite* tende à s’effacer devant son synonyme
> *rapide*.
>
> [ Banque de dépannage linguistique, OQLF « [*Vite* employé comme
> adverbe ou adjectif](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/22895/la-grammaire/ladverbe/vite-employe-comme-adverbe-ou-adjectif) » ]

Dans la langue familière au Québec je dirais que c'est omniprésent.

---

On le trouve aussi au lexique ([*Larousse en ligne*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/vite/82249), [*Usito*](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/vite)) et dans le *Bon usage* (Grevisse et Goosse, 14<sup>e</sup>, éd. Duculot, § 199 b) :

> L'adjectif, courant chez les [classiques](https://www.littre.org/definition/vite), se dit encore, pour l'[Ac.
> 1935](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A8V0646), « des animaux et de certaines choses dont le mouvement est
> rapide. *Cheval vite, fort vite, vite comme le vent. Il a le pouls
> fort vite* ». La langue des sports lui a rendu une certaine vitalité.
> Ex. littéraires : *Vous est-il défendu de la* [= une embarcation de
> fortune] *rendre plus* VITE ? (FRANCE, *île des Pingouins*, I, 3.) —
> *Son parler est de plus en plus* VITE *et indistinct* (GIDE, *Journal*, 2 janv. 1923). — *La seconde balle* [de tennis], *quoique plus* VITE
> *que la première* [...] (FARRÈRE, *Civilisés*, XV). — *Il* [= un aviateur] *réclame sans cesse des appareils plus* VITES *et plus
> puissants* (BORDEAUX, *Vie héroïque de Guynemer*, III, 5). — *Le plus*
> VITE *des diablotins ne l'eût pas rattrapé à la course* (POURRAT,
> *Gaspard des Montagnes*, 1.1, 1931, p. 73). — *L'Amérique est le pays le plus* VITE *du monde* (MORAND, *Papiers d'identité*, p. 291). — *Il
> ne faudrait pas* [...] *décréter que tous les Yankees sont* [...]
> *congénitalement* VITES (A. ARNOUX, *Poésie du hasard*, p. 129). — *J'ai accepté des fatigues inutiles, comme de poursuivre un homme plus* VITE *que moi* (MONTHERL., cit. *Grand Lar. langue*).