# Is "le coureur le plus vite" actually in use?

Tags: usage

Following up on a [discussion in Github](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/pull/8920#issuecomment-1189880704), I would be interested in some factual information about the usage of the word *vite* as an adjective.

I have never heard that usage in 50 years of French (as a native French) so I was very much surprised to discover that *vite* can be used as an adjective; According to [*Le Robert*](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/vite):

> moderne, Sports Le coureur le plus vite.

A generic [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22le%20plus%20vite%22%20-possible) does not really show results so I am quite confused.

What would be a good, quantitative way to assess whether this expression is in actual use?

---

*Note: the question is in English as I would like to add the answers to the GitHub discussion as another perspective (no matter what the result is - I am very curious myself*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although very rare, it is definitely in use, if only by sport commentators.

See [Why does the word "vite" stay the same in adjective AND adverb form?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/23075/1109)